# How to update xml data in solr using weburl instead of command line post.sh method?

Tags: xml, solr, salesforce

I am generating xml on run time in a string variable using Apex in salesforce. I want to send this generated xml to solr server with the help of webUrl. means i directly want to post my xml data to solr without the help of command line.

Can anybody please suggest me how to do this.??

Comment: It's solr.xml or other solr config file or you want to index this xml in solr?

Comment: its run time generaed file its not solr.xml or any any oher solr server file.

Answer (score 2):

[You can send XML directly to Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages). For example

```
curl http://<hostname>:<port>/solr/update -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<add>
<doc boost="2.5"> <field name="employeeId">05991</field>
<field name="office" boost="2.0">Bridgewater</field> </doc> </add>'
```

Comment: Or --data-binary @xmlFileName if you already saved it to disk